# Titanium Appstore submission: "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, app-store, titanium

I uploaded my app to the AppStore and I received an email stating that I am "Missing Push Notification Entitlement". I am not using push notifications, but I am using local background notifications.

> Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>   Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.
>   After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>   Regards,
>   The App Store team>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Just a warning in case you intended to use push notifications and have forgotten the entitlement, if you do not require push notifications then you can ignore the warning.
If you do want to use push notifications however, you will need to add the relevant sections and permissions to your tiApp.xml file

You may still need to register your intent for notifications as per
[this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Local_Notifications)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there was something else going on that I recieved this alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting such email there might be the reason i listed below:

- It might be because App Id you have used for this App in that You have enabled Push Notification.
- So what happen with that is if you enable Push notification in App id & it will be not used in the App, They will expect it to be used once you enable.

  - If such issue i mentioned than you should edit App Id & disable Push notification.

I hope it will guide you.